# with what number do multisig addresses (non-P2SH) start?

Tags: multi-signature, p2sh

I have never seen a n-m address implemented as [multisig](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#multisig) (not P2SH). What number does it start with (i.e., regular addresses start with 1, p2sh start with 3 ...) ?

In other words, where do they fit in this table: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes?

Comment: if anyone has an example of non-P2SH multisig transaction, please do share it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no address type defined for raw multisig. If you want to send money to them, you'll need to construct the `scriptPubKeys` manually, or use the payment protocol (BIP 70-72).

In general, raw multisig is discouraged as it stores more data than necessary in the UTXO set (the database that all full nodes must maintain to be able to validate transactions).